Can't figure out how to edit bootable ISO file
I need to add file to windows 10 installation ISO.
I've mounted ISO, copyed everything with cp to another directory, added file to this directory , turned it back into ISO with mkisofs, but i cant boot with this changed ISO from ventoy(original ISO works fine).
I've tried many fixes on forums, but nothing seems to work and i cant understand why. I used something like that to turn it into the ISO:
sudo mkisofs -b boot/etfsboot.com -no-emul-boot -boot-load-seg 1984 -boot-load-size 8 -iso-level 3 -J -l -D -N -joliet-long -relaxed-filenames -V "WINSP" -o Windows10Debloated.iso win
pls help


EFI boot or BIOS boot? 2) Are you burning it to a CD or writing to a USB stick?



I think EFI. 2)I'm just puting it on flashdrive that has ventoy on it.


Why are you not using DISM commands to slipstream the file? Windows tools to modify Windows images are the best tools for the job.

etfsboot.com is Legacy Bootloader in Windows. You need to create Legacy+UEFI boot or only UEFI boot. The file is efisys.bin  and I believe you need to use -eltorito-alt-boot   switch in your command to include that.
